# How can I refactor some repetitive HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, refactoring

How can I refactor the following repetitive HTML and CSS?

The code is about 10 rooms. The top of Room i is at 40*i pixels.

I used colons to indicate lines that I deleted.

HTML:

```
<div id="room1">Room 1</div>
<div id="room2">Room 2</div>
:
<div id="room10">Room 10</div>
```

CSS:

```
#room1,
#room2,
:
#room10
{
:
    top: 40px;
:
}

#room2 {top: 80px}
#room3 {top: 120px}
#room4 {top: 160px}
:
#room10 {top: 400px}
```

Comment: Is this better for the Code Review site?

Comment: Looks about as small as you're gonna get it.

Comment: are you looking to build a scheduler? with rooms down the left and times along the top to the right?

Comment: @Mauro: Yes, I'm trying to build a scheduler. Do you have any schedulers you could refer me to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this have to be in absolute positioning? Why not do this?

```
<div id="room1" class="roomHeight">Room 1</div>
<div id="room2" class="roomHeight">Room 2</div>
:
<div id="room10" class="roomHeight">Room 10</div>

.roomHeight {
    height: 40px;
}
```

Each room will still stack as they are naturally under block display, making each one 40px tall will get the same effect as using absolute positioning and declaring the top of each div.

Answer (score 4):

If you require the `relative`/`absolute` positioning, there is no cleaner way to specify a different `top` for `n` different `div`s.

Sorry, but you just have to write it all out <strike>exactly</strike> similar to how you have it. After making this myself, I think I have something slightly shorter than yours.

---

For reference, this is how I'd do it if I needed the positioning:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/gQ86A/2/)

**CSS:**

```
#roomContainer {
    position: relative
}
#roomContainer div {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100px;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 1px solid blue
}

#room1  { top: 0px    }
#room2  { top: 40px    }
#room3  { top: 80px    }
#room99 { top: 9120px  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="roomContainer">
    <div id="room1">Room 1</div>
    <div id="room2">Room 2</div>
    <div id="room3">Room 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ... but if you'd use a sane element flow you can replace all this by simple putting one element beneath the other.

Comment: @Georg Schölly: Yup, I agree. I'm assuming he *needs* the positioning.

Comment: why are you setting the container as absolute and the inner divs to relative? I suppose it should be the opposite...

Answer (score 1):

give each the same class and make the class separate each correctly like:

```
<div id="room1" class="room">Room 1</div>
<div id="room2" class="room">Room 2</div>
:
<div id="room10" class="room">Room 10</div>
```

the css:

```
.room {
   margin-top: 40px
}
```

I'm not sure why you used the top property, are they all positioned absolutely?

Answer (score 1):

First I'd suggest to give the "room" `div`s also a class for the common css properties: `<div id="room1" class="room"></div>` Or if all of them are in a common parent element use that to assign the common css properties:

```
<div id="allrooms">
  <div id="room1">Room 1</div>
  <div id="room2">Room 2</div>
</div>

#allrooms div {
  ...
}
```

If you don't want that list of css rules for all `div`s, it may be worth considering applying the `left` properties directly to the `div`s: `<div style="left: 20px">Room 1</div>`

Answer (score 0):

it might be better to use a div to wrap the entire row instead then...so you have a

    `<div class="schedulerRow">
        <div id="room1" class="room">room 1</div>
        <div id="scheduler1">Enter Time division elements in here</div>
    </div>`

Css
`.schedulerRow, room { height: 40px;}`

then you can interact with the time division elements on the same row without affecting the other room rows.