# Optimizing my CSS

Tags: html, css

I have CSS that looks like this:

```
div#sbar {position:absolute;top: 10px;bottom: 10px;left:10px; right: 10px;}
```

There's a lot that specifies left, right, top, bottom etc.  Is there any way that I can optimize / simplify the CSS. I wish there was a shortcut for this like there is for border.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some more code, like an example of how you use this code on the layout? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Shaz - why are you suggesting to use a property that does not do the same? And who votes that up?

Comment: @easwee: Wasn't sure if that worked or not, which is why I placed it as a comment. Just tested it out and seems as if you're right. Comment deleted, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no shorthand for top, bottom, left, right.

Comment: Does `top:10px;bottom:10px` even do anything?

Answer (score 2):

You can't shorten this:

```
div#sbar {position:absolute;top: 10px;bottom: 10px;left:10px; right: 10px;}
```

But you could shorten this:

```
div#sbar {position:absolute;top: 10px;bottom: 10px;left:10px; right: 10px;}
div#gbar {position:absolute;top: 10px;bottom: 10px;left:500px; right: 30px;}
div#nbar {position:absolute;top: 10px;bottom: 10px;left:50px; right: 200px;}
```

To this:

```
div#sbar, div#gbar, div#nbar { position:absolute; top: 10px; bottom: 10px }

div#sbar { left:10px; right: 10px }
div#gbar { left:500px; right: 30px }
div#nbar { left:50px; right: 200px }
```

This could be useful.

Also, there's no need to use `div` in `div#sbar`: `id`s are by definition unique, so there's no need to qualify the `id` with the tag name. Using it actually (*really, really* marginally) slows down your browser.

So this would be better (and more to the point, shorter):

```
#sbar, #gbar, #nbar { position:absolute; top: 10px; bottom: 10px }

#sbar { left:10px; right: 10px }
#gbar { left:500px; right: 30px }
#nbar { left:50px; right: 200px }
```

---

Here's an example where I actually did something very similar to what I've just suggested:

- [How can I refactor some repetitive HTML and CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378534/how-can-i-refactor-some-repetitive-html-and-css/5378592#5378592)

It actually worked out better in that question, because all the `div`s were contained in a common parent, so there was no need to list out the elements twice.

Answer (score 0):

An optimization tip: No need for `div` before `#sbar`

-- addendum --

Won't all of these attributes cancel each other out? Moving something down by `10px` then moving it up by `10px` will equal no movement.

Comment: They won't. In modern browsers this will position a div absolutely filling whole browser space except 10px around. Nice catch on the selector.

Comment: Really? You learn something new every day, cheers! No need for width, height or anything? Which browsers don't respect the rules?

Comment: This won't work in ie6. No width or anything needed to specify. Try a sample - http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/5ZHEy/

Comment: Lovely stuff, thanks for that. Interesting though as surely this goes against the top and bottom rules and what they are meant for. It's (essentially) adding a margin to an element, not changing the position of it.

Comment: No - you are getting it wrong. It doesn't add margin. It adds offset from parent element border on the defined side. Also they won't cancel each other out since they are each a different css property. Think how bottom:0 works. Positions element on the bottom of the parent. Same goes in this case only that your body is the parent.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah I see what you mean now. I suppose it affects the outer edges of an element and moves them, not the whole element itself.

Comment: Something like that. I suggest you check the official w3 recommandation - it might be abit tough to read trough but it is atleast explained corrrectly.

Comment: Might be worth a refresher, yeah. Weird that I've never come across this in all my years of coding CSS!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like:

```
div#sbar {position: absolute 10px 10px 10px 10px;}`
```

This doesn't exist however (as far as I know). it would be nice though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shorthand way of `top`, `bottom`, `left`, or `right`.

As for your CSS selector it self, it repeats it self twice. What I mean by this is that CSS parses from right to left.

If you have for example this: `div table tr td#myContent{}` Here is what happens:

`div table tr td`#myContent`{}`
 #myContent found!

`div table tr` td #myContent `{}`
We already found  #myContent, but okay!

`div table` tr td #myContent `{}`
I told you, we already found  #myContent...!

`div`table tr td #myContent `{}`
Like I said the other 3 times, **we already found  #myContent**!!!

div table tr td #myContent `{}`
...